# encode app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

Why do I have encode problems like this:

```
Olvid&oacute; su contrase&ntilde;a?
```

http://sandengine.appspot.com/?hl=es&device=mobile

I'm using UTF8 in the HTML, but the issue is in the backend.

This is an open source project and the code you can get it here.
https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to elaborate on what the actual problems are. What you are doing, what the result is and what you want the result to be instead. Also, if you want to learn about unicode, I suggest starting by watching http://bit.ly/unipain

Answer (score 2):

Your text is being HTML-encoded twice. You should only encode on output, not on storage.

Comment: yes, but in that kind of files I can't put these characters (á or é)... so, instead I have to write &aacute; or &eacute;